# Getting crash on iOS 12 with common signature for SVProgrssHUD

Tags: hockeyapp, ios12, svprogresshud, iphone-xs, iphone-xs-max

The application recently lived on iTunes store.

Hockey app reporting multiple common crash signature for iPhone Model XS and XS Max with iOS 12.

```
16  ??? 0x00000001054f4a78 -[SVProgressHUD updateMotionEffectForXMotionEffectType:yMotionEffectType:] (SVProgressHUD.m:536)
17  SVProgressHUD   0x00000001054f5468 -[SVProgressHUD positionHUD:] (SVProgressHUD.m:683)
18  SVProgressHUD   0x00000001054f6824 -[SVProgressHUD fadeIn:] (SVProgressHUD.m:872)
19  SVProgressHUD   0x00000001054f6108 __37-[SVProgressHUD showProgress:status:]_block_invoke (SVProgressHUD.m:812)
20  Foundation      0x00000001ba137064 0x1ba018000 + 1175652
```

Any updates with motion effect in iOS 12. I have done research and nothing found helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your library has a bug for iPhone XS and XS Max. There is an open Issue #930 [Here](https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD/issues/930) Without the full crashlog it is impossible to know much. What kind of Crash (For the bug it seems a SIGTRAP) etc...